# Does Barret's clustering coefficient interpret weighted edges as distance or strength?

Tags: r, igraph

Distance, as in, the larger the weight the weaker the connection, and strength, as in, the larger with weight the stronger the connection. I do not understand his formula, found here.

https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.0400087101

I found a similar question for more igraph functions that only references the documentation pages and formula, without answering the question.

https://igraph.discourse.group/t/r-igraph-edge-weights-should-be-interpreted-as-connection-strenghts-or-distances/1448/2

Thank you for your response.

Comment: The interpretation of weights is not generally as simple as "distance or strength". I suggest looking carefully at every network metric you use, and making sure that it is suitable for your specific use case.

Comment: In this situation, the paper is quite clear about the meaning of weights: "This coefficient is a measure of the local cohesiveness that takes into account the importance of the clustered structure on the basis of the **amount of traffic** or **interaction intensity** actually found on the local triplets." Larger weights are meant to represent "more important" or "stronger" connections. The two paragraphs preceding the formula present the authors' justification for this formulation, and again make the interpretation of weights clear.

Comment: Put simply, a big reason why I don't want to include too simplistic guidelines in the documentation is that in my experience this encourages naïve misuse of network analysis methods. I want you to take the time to look at the paper and read at least the three paragraphs that discuss this metric (not just the formula), and consider whether this metric is suitable for what you want to do, as well as use some common sense in the choice of your weights (beyond considering large value=strong vs large value=weak).